# Can not call the firebase.database() function in Node

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following configuration file in my nodejs project

```
const firebase = require('firebase/app');

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyBNMB7IdCKV7iObJDSSFTRVHp9M8ZndpZh2c",
  authDomain: "ivrs-d422d.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://ivrs-d422d.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "ivrs-d422d",
  storageBucket: "ivrs-d422d.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "10387822329211",
  appId: "1:1038786929211:web:6ed1a58fewqa9855105ef21e",
  measurementId: "G-ZTY9VS9EK9"
};

// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const db = firebase.database();
```

and i get the following error:

```
/Users/Documents/Market/config/firebaseConfiguration.js:26
  const db = firebase.database();
                      ^

TypeError: firebase.database is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> 
(/Users/Documents/Market/config/firebaseConfiguration.js:26:23)
```

Can someone explain why that is happening?

Comment: Please refer to the documentation on Firebase v9's breaking changes: [Modular Web SDK Upgrade Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase RTDB for Firebase v9](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69594428/3068190)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to use:

```js
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore"

const db = getFirestore()
```

for Realtime database.

```
import { getDatabase } from "firebase/database";
const database = getDatabase(app);
```

Docs for Realtime database setup https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start#initialize_the_javascript_sdk

Docs for Firestore setup https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#initialize

Comment: I am wanting to connect to the firebase realtime database and not firestore.

Comment: my bad.  seems like you're using Firebase 9, and setting up the old way.  
 firebase 9 broke things up so you wouldn't need to import the entire Firebase as far as I understand. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start#initialize_the_javascript_sdk      lmk if this work